# AWS ECS CodePipeline CodeDeploy TaskDefinition

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

In this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html, the document refers to a token called TASK_DEFINITION that is replaced by CodePipeline.

I am battling to find any official documentation around this token.  In the CodePipeline, you're able to specify the token that is looked for in your task definition, and has documentation.

Has anyone found/read any official documentation on this token?

Answer (score 0):

So basically every time we run the pipeline it will register the new task definition which will be using the new image from the ECR repo now as dynamically we are not sure about the task definition version which is getting registered, Pipeline will give us option to use placeholder  which will be replaced by newly created task definition Pipeline automatically when it will run.

So it will be just next revision number of task definition in complete ARN format.